# How to use ndk-r12 clang build app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang

My code works well by build in `ndk-r10` by `gcc` , I tried `ndk-r12 clang` ,no any build error, but the app runs crash, this is my build file, I used `C++11`, `std`, `freetype,`libpng`,`lua`,and`tinyxml2`

ndkinstall.sh

```
export NDK=/home/chen/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9  \
   --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-clang --use-llvm  \
   --stl=libc++  --install-dir=/usr/src/androidclangr12
```

Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -std=c++11
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

freetype.sh

```
export PATH=/usr/src/androidclangr12/bin:$PATH
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
LibDir=/usr/src/lib
FTDir=/home/freetype-2.6.2/
cd $FTDir
make distclean
CFLAGS="-std=gnu99" ./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/freetype --without-zlib --with-harfbuzz=no
make clean
make
cp ./objs/.libs/libfreetype.a $LibDir/libfreetype.a
```

Comment: _"app runs crash"_ What does the backtrace from the crash look like? Does it also crash if you build for `armeabi-v7a` instead of `armeabi`?

Comment: @Michael  only  armeabi , logcat output debugging information but without any error messages

Comment: I used thread， mutex, condition_variable and unordered_set, it just say: Unfortunately, ... has stopped.

Comment: Perhaps you've run into [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205734) (although it's supposed to have been fixed in r12). Why do you need to build for armeabi anyway? Phone manufacturers began switching to ARMv7 platforms about 5-6 years ago.

Comment: @Michael   I think I made a mistake because installed too many versions. armeabi-v7a and armeabi all crash when the version>10,it seems to be no longer supported  mutex and condition_variable,has anyone successfully compiled and run through it?